# jQuery .live() method by class selector and die method by id selector

Tags: jquery

I've a "problem" with .live() and .die() methods.
I'm using jQuery 1.5.1.
Here is my scenario

```
<div id='div1' class='MyClass'>Link 1</div>
<div id='div2' class='MyClass'>Link 2</div>
<div id='div3' class='MyClass'>Link 3</div>
```

and my jQuery script

```
$('.MyClass').live('click', function(evt) {
   local.href = 'home.aspx'
});
```

for some reason I want to disable Link 2 so I've tried to do this

```
$('#div2').die('click');
```

but it doesn't seem to works fine.
I think that if I add an event using class selector I can't remove the same event using id selector.
I must use .live() method because I don't know how many div I'll have in my page.

Anyone have any suggestions to "fix" this problem?

Comment: There's a difference between not knowing how many divs you have on a page and dynamically adding the divs *after* the page loads.  Live is only necessary in this latter scenario.  For the former scenario, `.bind('click')` will work fine.  As far as live on class selector and die on id selector, that should work fine.  What do you mean by "not work"?  If you can be more specific, we can help out.  Try 'div.MyClass' in your selector just in case.

Comment: **Read the documentation first [here](http://api.jquery.com/die/):** *"Note: In order for .die() to function correctly, the selector used with it must match exactly the selector initially used with .live()."*

Comment: @Faber Removing the `MyClass` class from that particular DIV would solve the issue automatically. Is that doable for you?

Comment: @Milimetric The OP used future tense - he said that he doesn't know how many DIV's he **will** have on the page. This means that more DIV's are added dynamically which makes it the latter scenario.

Comment: @Milimetric I don't know how many divs I will find in my page. I add divs dynamically, so I need to use .live()

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yeah! It's works fine!!! I've remove the class from the div and it works fine! Thank you!

Comment: @Faber So, you use that class *only* to bind the live-handler to that DIV's? You don't have any CSS associated with that class?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yes, the class is only used to bind click event. I use "fake" class to bind events on multiple object in the page without assign any CSS style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the class 'MyClass' from div2. Then it won't match the selector for the live binding.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ENmcw/)

Answer (score 0):

something else to try:

```
$('.mySelector').unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

One "hotfix" solution would be this:

```
$('.MyClass').live('click', function(evt) {
    if ( $(this).data('disabled') ) { return false; } // return if disabled
    // do your stuff
});
```

And then, when you want to disable a DIV, do this:

```
$('#div2').data('disabled', true);
```

Now, the live-handler will still execute, but it will immediately return.

You can even re-enable it later by setting the above data-attribute to `true`.